# Segmentation Fault when calling member of a struct

Tags: c, string, struct, char, stack

sorry if this has been asked a million times before, but I think I have a problem understanding how strings (char arrays) work in C.

In my program, I have a "stack" struct, which looks like this (in stack.h):

```
struct stack_t {
/* Stack-Datentyp */
/* Stacks have a head-node, a length, and a name.
Stacks are filled with links (nodes) that are defined below. These links have
a generic data pointer and a pointer to the next link */
link head;                      
unsigned int length;            
char *name;                     //stack name
};

typedef struct stack_t *stack;
```

in my main.c, I call a function called "stack_new" which seems to work properly, since all the printf-calls work:

```
stack stack_new(char *stackname) {
  /* creates a new, empty stack */
stack st = (stack)(malloc(sizeof(stack)));
if (st == NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory for Stack could not be allocated!\n");
return NULL;
}
st->head = NULL;
printf("head works.\n");
st->length = 0;
printf("length works.\n");
st->name = stackname;
printf("stackname works.\n");
return st;
}
```

Now, when I call this function in main.c, I get a seg fault. Here is the call:

```
if (strcmp(input,"newstack") == 0) {
    printf("Please enter stackname:\n");
    scanf("%s", &stackname);
    printf("Debug: Input works.\n");
    stacklist[NumberOfStacks] = stack_new(stackname);
    printf("stack created works-\n");
    NumberOfStacks++;
    printf("A new stack with the name '%s' was created!\nIt is number %d in stack list.", stacklist[NumberOfStacks]->name, NumberOfStacks);
    continue;
}
```

The seg fault happens when I try to print the member name of the struct stacklist[NumberOfStacks] points to. What am I doing wrong here?

I also get a bunch of warnings that tell me about how my scanf for stackname expects a different type:

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’ [-Wformat=]
>        scanf("%s", &stackname);

Other warnings I get tell me that I am not typecasting from my void-pointer I use for data storage in the stack nodes, but I don't think that this is relevant to my problem here.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
The problem was that I incremented NumberOfStacks before using it as index for printing the member of a struct saved in the array.

```
NumberOfStacks++;
    printf("A new stack with the name '%s' was created!\nIt is      number %d in stack list.", stacklist[NumberOfStacks]->name, NumberOfStacks);
```

This part of the program works fine now, thanks!

Comment: `stack st = (stack)(malloc(sizeof(stack)));` --> `stack st = malloc(sizeof(*st));`

Comment: `stacklist[NumberOfStacks]->name` :  `stacklist[NumberOfStacks]` maybe uninitialize. Because it increments to this before (`NumberOfStacks++;`)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It is still not working, same segmentation fault.
NumberOfStacks is initialized (0). I changed the malloc and it is still faulting.

Comment: `void *` does not need to cast in C.

Comment: I'm guessing that you've defined `stackname` in `main` as `char stackname[50]`. In that case `scanf("%s", &stackname);` means that you're passing a **pointer to array of char**, not a **pointer to char**. Just pass `stackname` as is: `scanf("%s", stackname);`. [The **array of char** expression is automatically converted to **pointer to char** expression](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) that points to the 1st element. You're also allowing the buffer to overrun in this case.

Comment: I changed `&stackname` to just `stackname`. The error, of course, persists. What do you mean by buffer overrunning? Is the problem here that I am copying the string wrong or did not allocate memory for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of bugs in your code. Most have been addressed in the comments. I have made the corrections and it seems to work without segfault.
The modifications are indicated by comments in the code.

This is the code I ended up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Prototype for malloc
#include <stdlib.h>
// Prototype for strdup
#include <string.h>

typedef void *link; /* Added to make it compile - you may have a different definition in your code */

struct stack_t {
    /* Stack-Datentyp */
    /* Stacks have a head-node, a length, and a name.
     * Stacks are filled with links (nodes) that are defined below. 
     * These links have
     * a generic data pointer and a pointer to the next link */
    link head;
    unsigned int length;
    char *name;                     //stack name
};

typedef struct stack_t *stack;

stack stack_new(char *stackname) {
    /* creates a new, empty stack */
    stack st = malloc(sizeof(*st));    // changed to use the variable name
    if (st == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory for Stack could not be allocated!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    st->head = NULL;
    printf("head works.\n");
    st->length = 0;
    printf("length works.\n");
    st->name = strdup(stackname);  // Changed: Duplicate the name so it won't get overwritten when creating the next stack
    printf("stackname works.\n");
    return st;
}


int main(void)
{
    char stackname[50];       // Added declaration for stackname.
    stack stacklist[50];      // Added declaration. Can handle up to 50 stacks.
    int NumberOfStacks = 0;

    printf("Please enter stackname:\n");
    scanf("%s", stackname);              // Changed. Removed the "&" since stackname is a char*.
    printf("Debug: Input works.\n");
    stacklist[NumberOfStacks] = stack_new(stackname);
    printf("stack created works-\n");
    // All data is at index 0, so cannot use increased value of NumberOfStacks to get get the data. Also changed the text to "has index" since a 0 will be printed for stacknumber.
    printf("A new stack with the name '%s' was created!\nIt has index %d in stack list.\n", stacklist[NumberOfStacks]->name, NumberOfStacks);
    NumberOfStacks++;    // Moved this line down.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already incorporated all the changes you proposed, and it works now. The problem was my incrementation, where you changed the position of it.

Answer (score 0):

For the warning, scanf is waiting for a type 'pointer to char'. Your variable 'stackname' is declared as 'char stackname[50]' (I think, you haven't posted the declaration).
Use &stackname means you want to access the address of the array. Use of stackname or &stackname is almost the same because in the first case, the array will be converted to a pointer to the first case of the array and in the second case, it will be the address of the array wich is the first case of the array.

If you want to copy a string, you must allocate a buffer of the size of the string (with malloc) and use strcpy.

For the segfault, show us the declaration of stacklist and NumberOfStacks. The cause may be the value of NumberOfStacks is greater than the size of the array.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. My declarations are here:

    `unsigned int exit = 0, NumberOfStacks = 0;`  
    `unsigned int MAXSTACKS = 50;`  
    `stack stacklist[MAXSTACKS];  
    for(j=0;j<MAXSTACKS;j++) {  
    stacklist[j] = NULL;  
  }`

(I suck at formatting.)

Now that I look at it, my stacklist is an array of stack-types, which are pointers to stacks. Is that a wise thing to do?

Comment: _If you want to copy a string, you must allocate a buffer of the size of the string (with malloc) and use strcpy._

If that was my error, wouldn't I get a segfault when creating a new stack, since the memory for the string was not allocated? Does
    `st->name = stackname`
not work, do I have to use strcpy in this case?

Comment: @mneumann Since you need to both allocate memory and copy the data, `st->name=strdup(stackname)` would be a good choice.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck thank you. I still get the same segfault, though.

Comment: @Pouet_forever Wow, I just found the error and feel stupid. Since I incremented, printf received NumberOfStacks + 1... Thanks for the help!